# How to change pivot columns order

Tags: pandas

I would like to change the order of the pivot columns. How can I change this?

Are there any parameters in the pivot_table method?

Change from this:

```
| category | B | C | A |
|categoryA | 
|    adult | 
|    child | 
|categoryB | 
|    adult | 
|    child | 
|categoryC | 
|    adult | 
|    child |
```

To this:

```
| category | A | B | C |
|categoryA | 
|    adult | 
|    child | 
|categoryB | 
|    adult | 
|    child | 
|categoryC | 
|    adult | 
|    child |
```

Comment: Do you need `df = df.sort_index(axis=1)` ?

Comment: Or `df = df.reindex(columns=['A','B','C'])` ?

Comment: I have error. TypeError: Expected tuple, got str. so I asked. Is anything worng?

Comment: What is your code for pivot ?

Comment: df = df.pivot_table(values=['id'], index=['category' 'section'], columns=['method'], aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
df = df.reindex(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

Comment: Remove `[]` like `df = df.pivot_table(values='id', index=['category', 'section'], columns='method', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0) `